# Does it hold that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ imply $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^2(\Omega)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, sequence-of-function

My question is simply as the title suggests. If I am not mistaken, the norm of the Sobolev space is "stronger" but I have yet to figure out what this means in this context. I do appreciate any input.

Comment: For $f\in W^{1,2}$ the norm is the sum the $L^2 $ norms of $f$ and $Df$ (or equivalent to this sum). So $W^{1,2}$ convergence of $f_n$ implies $L^2$ convergence of $f_n$ and $Df_n$.

Comment: Thank you, I realise it now as I am looking at the natural norm of the Sobolev space.